# Action class method not executed after validation in spring Webflow

Tags: java, spring-webflow, spring-validator

I have added a validation in my flow and it works fine, the only problem is I am not able to execute my action class method after the validation. If I remove the validation it works fine.

Here is what my flow.xml looks like

```
<view-state id="myView" view="newView" model="viewModel">
<transition on="doChangeView" to="doChangeView" />
<transition on="done" to="home" validate="false" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="doChangeView">
    <evaluate expression="viewAction.doChangeView" />
    <transition on="done" to="home"  />
</action-state>
```

I am guessing that I am not setting the flow correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "return to my action class"?

Comment: I mean when I debug after validation it does not go to the action class.

Comment: are you sure it's passing the validation?

Comment: Yes, i am checking if the fields are empty or not with the validation and it seems to be working fine. Once I enter some values in the field it is supposed to execute the method in my action class and that is not happening.

Comment: can you post the logs showing the transition being made to doChangeView state?

Comment: you are welcome :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, after looking through logs I found that there was some error in the validation method. After resolving it I was able to execute the method in my action class.